# WordPress Move only Javascript to footer

Tags: php, wordpress

Right now I am using a very simple function to move the javascript of WordPress to the footer:

```
function move_javascripts() {
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 1 );
    add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 5 );
}
```

The problem though is that this code seems to bring all the "scripts" to the footer, even the CSS... I've tried to find a way to move only the .js part but I can't find any...

So is there some way to only target the javascripts and move them to the footer without the CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are pretty much overkilling the whole WordPress Script system with this and to be honest - this is completely, I mean totally wrong. When you enque a script into WordPress you do this by `wp_enqueue_script`.

This function takes 5 parameters, of which the last one can be set to true, in order to load it in the footer.

Here is an excerpt of my functions.php:

```
if (!function_exists('wp_template_setup')) {

    wp_enqueue_script('modernizr-script', get_template_directory_uri() .   '/js/libs/modernizr.custom.js', '', '', true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_template_setup');
```

The last paramter is set to true, which means that it will be loaded in the footer.

See the WordPress Codex for details: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Comment: Hmm, so if I am using a theme like _s, it would mean that I need to find where these scripts are added then simply set that 5th parameter to true?

Comment: Well actually all the JS from this theme were already in the footer... Guess I will have to go directly in WP code to fix the ones called by WordPress itself

Comment: Noooo, don't fiddle at the core of WordPress - everything in WordPress can be modified - without touching WP Core files *at all*. To your first comment - yes you can do that. Go to your theme folder, look for the function that enqueues it - set 5th parameter to true - you are done.

Comment: Ah, I also thought modifying WP core did not seem like a good idea. I found this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/173601/enqueue-core-jquery-in-the-footer which seems to do roughly what I want

Answer (score 0):

In your `wp_register_script()` calls (where the scripts are enqueued), there is a 5th parameter called `$in_footer` which is designed for this very thing. Throw a `true` in there and it'll move the script to the footer. Note, you'll have to the do this on each `wp_register_script()` call.